How to efficiently compare 2 dataframe and produce a column value based on condition
data1 = {
    'alias_cd': ['12345', '12345', '12345'],
    'country_cd': ['AU', 'AU', 'AU2'],
    'pos_name': ['st1', 'Jh', 'Jh'],
    'ts_allocated': [100, 100, 100],
    'tr_id': ['None', 'None', 'None'],
    'ty_name': ['E2E', 'E2E', 'E2E']
}

data2 = {
    'alias_cd': ['12345', '12345'],
    'country_cd': ['AU', 'AU3'],
    'pos_name': ['st1', 'st2'],
    'ts_allocated': [200, 100],
    'tr_id': ['None', 'None'],
    'ty_name': ['E2E', 'E2E']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

output should be
   alias_cd country_cd pos_name  ts_allocated          tr_id    ty_name  etl_flag
1  12345            AU  st1      200                   None      E2E     U
2  12345           AU3  st2      100                   None      E2E     D
3  12345            AU  st1      100                   None      E2E     I
4  12345            AU  Jh       100                   None      E2E     I
5  12345           AU2  Jh       100                   None      E2E     I

Because:
The combination of alias_cd and country_cd acts as a primary key.
1.If a combination exists in df2 and df1 (12345 AU), it will be marked for 'Update' in df2, and all corresponding rows in df1 for the same combination will be marked as 'Insert'. for the above example for 12345 AU records in df2 will be etl_flag= 'Update' and add records for the same combination from df1 to df2 with etl_flag as 'Insert'
2.12345 AU3 exists in df2 but not in df1, so it will be tagged as 'DELETE' in the etl_flag column.
3.Any new combination that appears in df1 and not present in df2 will be tagged as 'Insert' in the etl_flag column.
How can I achieve this efficiently?
This is what I tried but its doesn't give correct output:
df2['etl_flag'] = 'U'

to_insert = df1[~df1.apply(lambda x: (df2['alias_cd'] == x['alias_cd']) & (df2['country_cd'] == x['country_cd']), axis=1)]
to_insert['etl_flag'] = 'I'
df2 = pd.concat([df2, to_insert], ignore_index=True)

to_delete = df2[~df2.apply(lambda x: (df1['alias_cd'] == x['alias_cd']) & (df1['country_cd'] == x['country_cd']), axis=1)]
to_delete['etl_flag'] = 'D'

final_df = pd.concat([df2, to_delete], ignore_index=True)
final_df.sort_values(by=['alias_cd', 'country_cd'], inplace=True)

print(final_df[['alias_cd', 'country_cd', 'pos_name', 'ts_allocated', 'tr_id', 'ty_name', 'etl_flag']])


the logic is unclear, why is 12345/AU2 assigned an I?

@mozway 12345/AU2 will be 'I' because this is not present in df2, its a new combination.

OK, so any row in df1 will always get a I

IIUC, you can first perform a left-merge with indicator on df2 to identify the U/D status, then concat. df1 always gets an I:
# columns used as primary key
cols = ['alias_cd', 'country_cd']

out = pd.concat(
    [df2.assign(etl_flag=df2.merge(df1[cols].drop_duplicates(),
                                   on=cols, how='left', indicator=True)
                ['_merge'].map({'left_only': 'D', 'both': 'U'})
                .values),
     df1.assign(etl_flag='I')]
)

Output:
  alias_cd country_cd pos_name  ts_allocated tr_id ty_name etl_flag
0    12345         AU      st1           200  None     E2E        U
1    12345        AU3      st2           100  None     E2E        D
0    12345         AU      st1           100  None     E2E        I
1    12345         AU       Jh           100  None     E2E        I
2    12345        AU2       Jh           100  None     E2E        I

